# Animate divs when others disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have a layout of divs that all 'clear', like in a list. I use jQuery's built in fadeOut function to make them disappear after a certain amount of time. That all works great. The divs disappear one at a time starting from the top. jQuery uses to fading opacity and finally display:none to 'fadeOut' the div. When the top div finally fades out (to display:none) the divs underneath it all move up, but they jump up. I was wondering if there is a way to make this a smooth (slide) transition? TIA

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific use case is, but you should check out http://greensock.com/, and especially watch the timeline tip tutorial/demo - http://greensock.com/position-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do your animation before setting the display:none to you your previous div. Set first div opacity to 0, move your second div to the fist div position with a setInterval or setTimeout, then hide your first div with display:none ... then rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I kind of implemented this. I ended up just doing two sequential animations with CSS. Fading it first with opacity and then shrinking the size to 0. Kind of a "going, going, gone" sort of logic.